# Telling Bullet That Something Happened In The Past

Tags: c++, network-programming, synchronization, bulletphysics, time-management

Is it possible to tell bullet that something has happened in the past so it can take this information and adjust internal interpolation to show this change in the present?
There would never be a need to go back in time more than 1-5 seconds, 5 being a very rare occasion, more realistically between 1.5 and 2.5 seconds is where most of the change would occur.

The ability to query an objects position, rotation, and velocities at a specific time in the past would be needed as well, but this can easily be accomplished.

The reason behind all of this would be to facilitate easier synchronization of two physics simulations, specifically in a networked environment.

A server constantly running the simulation in real-time would send position, rotation, and velocity updates to client simulations at periodic intervals. These updates would arrive at the client 'in the past' from the client simulation's perspective due to network latency, thus the need to query the updated objects values in the past to see if they are different arises, if they are different the need to change these values in the past is also necessary. During the next simulation step bullet would take these past-changes into account and update the object accordingly.

Is this ability present in bullet or would it need to be emulated somehow? If emulation is needed could someone point me in the correct direction to getting started on this "rewind and replay" feature?

If you are unfamiliar with "rewind and replay" this article goes into great detail about the theory behind implementation for someone who may be going about creating their own physics library. http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/n ... d-physics/

Comment: It is not present in Bullet out-of-the-box, but you certainly can do it yourself. 

Just store state of your simulation from previous steps or even per client.
If new information about the "past" as you put it arrives, just load that older state into a simulation and advance it to the present again to get the new results.